# How do you bind data to multiple columns in a list view?

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, listview

I have a datasource that I want to bind to a listview that has multiple columns. How do I bind my datasource to that listview

Here is some pseudo code that doesn't work to help illustrate what I am trying to do:

```
MyDataTable dt = GetDataSource();
ListView1.DataBindings.Add("Column1.Text", dt, "MyDBCol1");
ListView1.DataBindings.Add("Column2.Text", dt, "MyDBCol2");
```

-- edit --

Sorry, I forgot to mention it was winforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is a lacuna in functionality of WinForms ListView control (thought it's possible to [databind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750972.aspx#BindingDatatoaListView) new WPF ListBox).

This article by Nick Karnik describes how to add databinding capability to custom control inherited from WinForms ListView - [Data binding a ListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ListView_DataBinding.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify whether this is winforms vs webforms? Both have a `ListView`. From the `DataBindings.Add` I'm assuming winforms.

Would `DataGridView` be a pragmatic option? This will support multi-column binding out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

Listview has no Datasource, Items must be added manually.

I would suggest to use the DatagridView instead of the Listview.
Particularly if you have a **lot of items**.

Answer (score -3):

Check out this [reference on binding datasource to listview](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221035838/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/rashid/archive/2007/09/09/Asp.net-ListView---DataBinding.aspx).  Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: This link talks about ASP.NET ListView and not the Winforms ListView.