# Copying ListView to ListView - C# .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I'm trying to access a ListView object from another thread. The way I'm doing it is creating a temporary ListView for the new thread, then copying this temporary ListView back to the original every second as the new list gets populated.

I'm having difficulty copying the ListView objects though. I've looked around and found ways of copying the items, but I also need the columns and structure to be the same too.

If I simply do:

`ListView lv_temp = lv_original`

then it copies it by reference, and I'll get more thread access errors.

So how do I make a complete clone by value?

Comment: Just don't.  Create only the data in a thread.  Stuff it, say, a List<>.  Populate the ListView only on the UI thread.  BackgroundWorker makes it easy.

Comment: Yes, what @Hans said. A proper datasource must be used.

Comment: That's sort of what I did. I just wanted to copy an entire ListView because the structure is already there. I just created a new structure with the same columns, then copied it row by row to the real one.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to deep copy the list, so you can use this extension:

```
/// <summary>
/// Reference Article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/SerializedObjectCloner.aspx
/// 
/// Provides a method for performing a deep copy of an object.
/// Binary Serialization is used to perform the copy.
/// </summary>

public static class ObjectCopier
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Perform a deep Copy of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of object being copied.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">The object instance to copy.</param>
    /// <returns>The copied object.</returns>
    public static T Clone<T>(T source)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");
        }

        // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (stream)
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, may I ask why are you doing this, why don't you pass the list to another thread and thats all (given that you're modifying it back again). If it's a UI control (wich might be fot what I see), you can use a background ItemsSource (from the other thread) and then use it as source on the UI using a Dispatcher. If that's what you want let me know to provide more details.

Comment: Good solution - however I'll try the source method up here first. This way would require to add yet another source in my bibliography.

Comment: Sure, that's the solution I mention (don't explain however) on my second paragraph. Good luck :)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think this is way off from what the OP is *actually* trying to achieve - IMO, the question is *"how to update my listview when the data is updated without a cross-threading exception"*

Comment: @IAbstract Sure, I understand that but, the question was different. I try to solve the given question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an object as a DataSource. When your datasource gets updated, the UI control gets updated. Otherwise, if you run into threading issues, use the the `SynchronizationContext.Current` and assign to a `sync` field member, then:

```
  // since I believe you don't have lambdas in .net 2.0 I'll try to write this out proper
  // although it is untested, but I hope you get the idea
  sync.Send(new SendOrPostCallback(SendCallBack), stateObject);

  void SendCallBack(object state) {
     // perform UI tasks here
  }
```

[SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is new in .net 2.0

...again, this is untested but is where I would start if I had to. Just as an aside, in .net 3.0(?) to present, we write:

```
  sync.Send((state) => {
     // perform UI tasks here
  }, stateObject);
```

**Update**
Found an answer [How do you bind ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/267410/210709). So there isn't a DataSource property as I had originally presumed.

Comment: That looks neat. I'll see if it works. It must be sortable with my Quicksort function though - so as long as it's IComparable, I should be okay. Otherwise, I need to make a comparer like I have for ListView objects.

Comment: You should create a datasource for your listview. You can then implement any behaviors you wish.

Comment: Neither this answer or the other answer have been useful. It's not worth the effort trying to force a data source into a ListView, so I gave up and copies column for column, row for row.

Comment: Then there is something that we are missing about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Nothing missing, just too sketchy doing it this way. The problem is still identical, but all I really needed to copy between the ListViews was the columns and item rows: everything else was irrelevant.

Comment: I guess what we don't understand is why you are copying controls instead of the data within the controls. ;)